# How to get ng-Model Value for ContentEditable Div

Tags: html, angularjs, contenteditable, angular-ngmodel

I have a div that is contenteditable=true. I am doing this because I need to insert initial values with raw html. Here is the div:

```
<div class="form-control col-sm-6" contenteditable="true" id="specialtextarea" ng-model="sv.GroupMembers" ng-bind-html="sv.GroupMembers"></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the div:

```
#specialtextarea {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 175px;
}
```

In my angular controller, I try to get the value like so:

```
$scope.ValueFromDiv = $scope.sv.GroupMembers;
```

It is undefined. I CAN get the value via:

```
$scope.ValueFromDiv = document.getElementById("specialtextarea");
```

Now, if I set the value of sv.GroupMembers with the initial load of the angular controller, I can get the value that I set, but I cannot get any values that I change it to.

Example:

```
$scope.sv = {};
$scope.sv.GroupMembers = 'Hello World';
```

By doing that, I will get the value: "Hello World", even if I change it to "Hello Universe".

How do I get the updated value?

I also tried to add ng-change to the div like so:

```
ng-change="getUpdatedValue(sv.GroupMembers);"
```

The function definition was:

```
$scope.getUpdatedValue = function(item){
    alert(item);
};
```

But that was never hit, no matter what I typed in the div.

Please help...

Comment: Hi Crackedcornjimmy, can you try ?by this "$scope.sv "

Comment: ng-model is valid only for input,select, textarea (or custom form control). please see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel.